# Piping grep output into grep inside a bash

Tags: bash, grep, pipe

I've got a text file, and I want to search for lines that have search_string but do not have exclude_string.

In terminal, the following gives me the output I want:

```
grep "search_string" | grep -v "\(exclude_string_A\|exclude_string_B\)"
```

I have a bash script which scans text files for particular issues (mostly using grep and sed), and I'd like to add this search to it, but I can't seem to make it work. It doesn't seem like the output of the first grep command is being used as the input for the second.

For example, for a file containing:

```
Gary: yes, that's what I said.  
Paul: well, I didn't hear you.  
Gary: okay, let's go.
```

In the bash script, the relevant line is:

```
grep "Gary:" | grep -v "\(said\|told\)" $1
```

But the output file contains for that section:

```
Paul: well, I didn't hear you.  
Gary: okay, let's go.
```

I hope there's something simple I'm missing here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea is right, but your input file/string argument is in the wrong place. It should have been written as

```
grep "Gary:" "$1" | grep -v "\(said\|told\)"
```

which means apply the first `grep` expression to match *all* the lines containing `Gary` and filter lines containing the words `said` or `told`.

With your attempt, since run with a pipeline, both the `grep` processes start, but the part after `|` processes the input `$1` as if it were a file instead of getting input from standard input over from the pipe and prints the couple of lines you are seeing.

But at this time, you are seeing the terminal hanging because the first `grep` is still waiting for input on its standard input stream, but it is not seeing one. Pressing the <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> sends the SIGINT signal which kills the pipeline eventually.